# What type corresponds to a xor b in type theory?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory, curry-howard

At the end of [Category Theory 8.2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXZR1v3YN-8), Bartosz Milewski shows some examples of the correspondence between logic, category theory, and type systems.

I was wandering what corresponds to the logical xor operator. I know that

```
a xor b == (a ∨ b) ∧ ¬(a ∧ b) == (a ∨ b) ∧ (¬a ∨ ¬b)
```

so I've solved only part of the problem: `a xor b` corresponds to `(Either a b, Either ? ?)`. But what are the two missing types?

It seems that how to write `xor` actually boils down to how to write `not`.

So what is `¬a`? My understanding is that `a` is logical true if there exist an element (at least one) of type `a`. So for `not a` to be true, `a` should be false, i.e. it should be `Void`. Therefore, it seems to me that there are two possibilities:

```hs
(Either a Void, Either Void b) -- here I renamed "not b" to "b"
(Either Void b, Either a Void) -- here I renamed "not a" to "a"
```

But in this last paragraph I have the feeling I'm just getting the wrong end of the dog.

(Follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64394487/if-either-can-be-either-left-or-right-but-not-both-then-why-does-it-correspond).)

Comment: Another possible interpretation of xor is "not isomorphic"

Comment: @luqui why? `Int` and `[Int]` are not isomorphic (are they?), but they are both inhabitated, hence both true, hence they xor to false. I'd this is not the case, where's my mistake?

Comment: hmm, yes my mistake.  I guess I meant "not equivalent", taking equivalent in the logical sense `(A -> B) and (B -> A)`.  This still lawfully conforms to xor from boolean logic, but it is intuitionistically weaker than the one in Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard trick for negation is to use `-> Void`, so:

```
type Not a = a -> Void
```

We can construct a total inhabitant of this type exactly when `a` is itself a provably uninhabited type; if there are any inhabitants of `a`, we cannot construct a total inhabitant of this type. Sounds like a negation to me!

Inlined, this means your definition of xor looks like one of these:

```
type Xor a b = (Either a b, (a, b) -> Void) -- (a ∨ b) ∧ ¬(a ∧ b)
type Xor a b = (Either a b, Either (a -> Void) (b -> Void)) -- (a ∨ b) ∧ (¬a ∨ ¬b)
```

Comment: Your second version seems a bit awkward to me, since the two `Either`s must go opposite ways. A third formulation: `Either (a, b -> Void) (b, a -> Void)`.

Comment: @dfeuer, can you elaborate? I don't understand if you are highlighting an inaccuracy or just the fact that, among the 4 possible choices, those chosen by Daniel are nicer/uglier than the remaining ones.

Comment: @Enrico, nothing inaccurate about it. But using it to get other formulations involves extra case branches to show absurdity.