# If Either can be either Left or Right but not both, then why does it correspond to OR instead of XOR in Curry-Howard correspondence?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, boolean-logic, category-theory, curry-howard

When I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380092/what-type-corresponds-to-a-xor-b-in-type-theory), one of the answers, now deleted, was suggesting that the type `Either` corresponds to XOR, rather than OR, in the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), because it cannot be `Left` and `Right` at the same time.

Where is the truth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The confusion stems from the Boolean truth-table exposition of logic. In particular, when both arguments are True, OR is True, whereas XOR is False. Logically it means that to prove OR it's enough to provide the proof of one of the arguments; but it's okay if the other one is True as well--we just don't care.

In Curry-Howard interpretation, if somebody gives you an element of `Either a b`, and you were able to extract the value of `a` from it, you still know nothing about `b`. It could be inhabited or not.

On the other hand, to prove XOR, you not only need the proof of one argument, you must also provide the proof of the *falsehood* of the other argument.

So, with Curry-Howard interpretation, if somebody gives you an element of `Xor a b` and you were able to extract the value of `a` from it, you would conclude that `b` is uninhabited (that is, isomorphic to `Void`). Conversely, if you were able to extract the value of `b`, then you'd know that `a` was uninhabited.

The proof of falsehood of `a` is a function `a->Void`. Such a function would be able to produce a value of `Void`, given a value of `a`, which is clearly impossible. So there can be no values of `a`. (There is only one function that returns `Void`, and that's the identity on `Void`.)

Comment: for me, the key in your answer is its last sentence. thanks for saying it, others didn't. no one bothered to state the obvious, but it is the obvious that isn't known at all to a new learner. I kept trying to find such a function (besides `undefined`), but the point was exactly that it *didn't* exist. that means e.g. `XOR Char Int` value doesn't exist either. now it's clear what all this stuff is about. always state the obvious! thanks again. ---- so, saying `a -> Void` exists is the same as saying `a ~ Void`. (there probably is no other way to say it in ("simple"?) Haskell). correct?

Comment: @WillNess, not `~` in the Haskell sense. `Void` is unique up to unique isomorphism. `f :: XOR Char Int -> Void` exists, and is unique. `absurd` is its unique inverse.

Comment: @dfeuer according to Bartosz's answer, `f = id`. so that must mean `XOR Char Int` unifies with `Void`?

Comment: @WillNess, I think he was being a bit loose in his writing.

Comment: do you mean e.g. with your type, `type XOR a b = Either (a, b -> Void) (b, a -> Void)`, something like `f :: XOR Char Int -> Void ; f (Left (char,int_void)) = int_void 1; f (Right (int,char_void)) = char_void 'a'`? and then the point of it is, that `int_void` and `char_void` are non-existent?

Comment: @WillNess, yes. There are lots of empty types, all of them equivalent (isomorphic) in the most boring possible way (there's exactly one isomorphism between each pair). This is a general property of *initial objects* in category theory. Let `V1` and `V2` be initial objects. By def of init obj, there are unique `f :: V1 -> V2`, `g :: V2 -> V1`. `f . g :: V2 -> V2` and `g . f :: V1 -> V1`. By uniqueness, `f . g = id_V2` and `g . f = id_V1`. Why are empty types initial objects in **Hask**? There can be no meaningful difference between two functions when neither can actually be called.

Comment: @dfeuer thank you, this whole thing does become a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a value of type `P` *and* a value of type `Q` (that is, you have both a proof of `P` and a proof of `Q`), then you are still able to provide a value of type `Either P Q`.

Consider

```
x :: P
y :: Q
...

z :: Either P Q
z = Left x    -- Another possible proof would be `Right y`
```

While `Either` does not have a specific case that explicitly represents this situation (unlike `These`), it does not do anything to *exclude* it (as in *exclusive* OR).

This third case where both have proofs is a bit different than the other two cases where only one has a proof, which reflects the fact that "not excluding" something is a bit different than "including" something in intuitionistic logic, since `Either` does not provide a particular witness for this fact. However `Either` is not an XOR in the way that XOR would typically work since, as I said, it does not exclude the case where both parts have proofs. What [Daniel Wagner proposes in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64380164/2476735), on the other hand, is much closer to an XOR.

`Either` is kind of like an exclusive OR in terms of what its possible witnesses are. On the other hand, it is like an *inclusive* OR when you consider whether or not you can actually create a witness in four possible scenarios: having a proof of P and a refutation of Q, having a proof of Q and a refutation of P, having a proof of both or having a refutation of both.<sup>[1]</sup> While you can construct a value of type `Either P Q` when you have a proof of both P and Q (similar to an inclusive OR), you cannot distinguish this situation from the situation where only P has a proof or only Q has a proof using only a value of type `Either P Q` (kind of similar to an exclusive OR). Daniel Wagner's solution, on the other hand, is similar to exclusive OR on *both* construction and deconstruction.

It is also worth mentioning that [`These`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these) more explicitly represents the possibility of both having proofs. `These` is similar to *inclusive* OR on both construction and deconstruction. However, it's also worth noting that there is nothing preventing you from using an "incorrect" constructor when you have a proof of both P and Q. You could extend `These` to be even more representative of an inclusive OR in this regard with a bit of additional complexity:

```
data IOR a b
  = OnlyFirst  a       (Not b)
  | OnlySecond (Not a) b
  | Both       a       b

type Not a = a -> Void
```

The potential "wrong constructor" issue of `These` (and the lack of a "both" witness in `Either`) doesn't really matter if you are only interested in a proof irrelevant logical system (meaning that there is no way to distinguish between any two proofs of the same proposition), but it might matter in cases where you want more computational relevance in the logic.<sup>[2]</sup>

In the practical situation of writing computer programs that are actually meant to be executed, computational relevance is often extremely important. Even though `0` and `23` are both proofs that the `Int` type is inhabited, we certainly like to distinguish between the two values in programs, in general!

## Regarding "construction" and "destruction"

Essentially, I just mean "creating values of a type" by construction and "pattern matching" by destruction (sometimes people use the words "introduction" and "elimination" here, particularly in the context of logic).

In the case of Daniel Wagner's solutions:

- **Construction**: When you construct a value of type `Xor A B`, you must provide a proof of exactly one of `A` or `B` and a refutation of the other one. This is similar to exclusive or. It is not possible to construct a value of this *unless* you have a refutation of either `A` or `B` *and* a proof of the other one. A particularly significant fact is that you cannot construct a value of this type if you have a proof of both `A` and `B` and you *don't* have a refutation of either of them (unlike *inclusive* OR).
- **Destruction**: When you pattern match on a value of type `Xor A B`, you *always* have a proof of one of the types and a refutation of the other. It will *never* give you a proof of both of them. This follows from its definition.

In the case of `IOR`:

- **Construction**: When you create a value of type `IOR A B`, you must do exactly one of the following: (1) provide only a proof of `A` and a refutation of `B`, (2) provide a proof of `B` and a refutation of `B`, (3) provide a proof of both `A` and `B`. This is like inclusive OR. These three possibilities correspond exactly to each of the three constructors of `IOR`, with no overlap. Note that, unlike the situation with `These`, you cannot use the "incorrect constructor" in the case where you have a proof of both `A` and `B`: the only way to make a value of type `IOR A B` in this case is to use `Both` (since you would otherwise need to provide a *refutation* of either `A` or `B`).
- **Destruction**: Since the three possible situations where you have a proof of at least one of `A` and `B` are *exactly* represented by `IOR`, with a separate constructor for each (and no overlap between the constructors), you will *always* know *exactly* which of `A` and `B` are true and which is false (if applicable) by pattern matching on it.

## Pattern matching on `IOR`

Pattern matching on `IOR` works exactly like pattern matching on any other algebraic datatype. Here is an example:

```
x :: IOR Char Int
x = Both 'c' 3

y :: IOR Char Void
y = OnlyFirst 'a' (\v -> v)

f :: Not p -> IOR p Int
f np = OnlySecond np 7

z :: IOR Void Int
z = f notVoid

g :: IOR p Int -> Int
g w =
  case w of
    OnlyFirst  p q -> -1
    OnlySecond p q -> q
    Both       p q -> q

-- We can show that the proposition represented by "Void" is indeed false:
notVoid :: Not Void
notVoid = \v -> v
```

Then a sample GHCi session, with the above code loaded:

```
ghci> g x
3
ghci> g z
7
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup>This gets a bit more complex when you consider that some statements are undecidable and therefore you cannot construct a proof *or* a refutation for them.

<sup>[2]</sup>Homotopy type theory would be one example of a proof *relevant* system, but this is reaching the limit of my knowledge as of now.

Comment: David, I think I understand most of your answer; however I'm still puzzled by the bit where you write _Daniel Wagner's solution, on the other hand, is similar to exclusive OR on_ both _construction and deconstruction_; later you mention _inclusive OR on both construction and deconstruction_ as well. Could you clarify that parts a bit? I guess that examples like "I can declare this value but not this" (as you did in the first chunk of code) would help me understand your point, maybe.

Comment: Another thing that would probably help me is how I would use `IOR`. For instance, I see I can pattern-match against `Both`, as in `Both a b = Both 3 'c' :: IOR Int Char` is just fine and does what I expected. But how would I use `OnlyFirst`? Can I pattern match against it? This seems to be somewhat related to your mention of constrution and deconstruction, no?

Comment: @Enrico I added a bit more to the answer about that. Does that help?

Comment: It certainly helps. However I want to take some time to look carefully at the three answers together, as there's still something quite not clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps try replacing “proof” in the Curry-Howard isomorphism with “evidence”.

Below I will use *italics* for propositions and proofs (which I will also call evidence), the mathematical side of the isomorphism, and I will use `code` for types and values.

The question is: suppose I know the type for [values corresponding to] evidence that *P* is true (I will call this type `P`), and I know the type for evidence that *Q* is true (I call this type `Q`), then what is the type for evidence of the proposition *R* = *P* OR *Q*?

Well there are two ways to prove *R*: we can prove *P*, or we can prove *Q*. We could prove both but that would be more work than necessary.

Now ask what the type should be? It is the type for things which are either evidence of *P* or evidence of *Q*. I.e. values which are either things of type `P` or things of type `Q`. The type `Either P Q` contains precisely those values.

What if you have evidence of *P* AND *Q*? Well this is just a value of type `(P, Q)`, and we can write a simple function:

```
f :: (p,q) -> Either p q
f (a,b) = Left a
```

And this gives us a way to prove *P* OR *Q* if we can prove *P* AND *Q*. Therefore `Either` cannot correspond to xor.

---

### What is the type for *P* XOR *Q*?

At this point I will say that negations are a bit annoying in this sort of constructive logic.

Let’s convert the question to things we understand, and a simpler thing we don’t:

*P* XOR *Q* = (*P* AND (NOT *Q*)) OR (*Q* AND (NOT *P*))

Ask now: what is the type for evidence of NOT *P*?

I don’t have an intuitive explanation for why this is the simplest type but if NOT *P* were true then evidence of *P* being true would be a contradiction, which we say as proving FALSE, the unprovable thing (aka BOTTOM or BOT). That is, NOT *P* may be written in simpler terms as: *P* IMPLIES FALSE. The type for FALSE is called *Void* (in haskell). It is a type which no values inhabit because there are no proofs of it. Therefore if you could construct a value of that type you would have problems. IMPLIES corresponds to functions and so the type corresponding to NOT *P* is `P -> Void`.

We put this with what we know and get the following equivalence in the language of propositions:

*P* XOR *Q* = (*P* AND (NOT *Q*)) OR (*Q* AND (NOT *P*)) = (*P* AND (*Q* IMPLIES FALSE)) OR ((*P* IMPLIES FALSE) AND *Q*)

The type is then:

```
type Xor p q = Either (p, q -> Void) (p -> Void, q)
```

Comment: I follow you up to a point, but you got me at _I don't have an..._, :/

Comment: Yeah, I think it’s just unintuitive when you introduce FALSE (ie BOT) into logic. Maybe think of it as CONTRADICTION instead. If you can prove some contradiction, you can prove anything (because FALSE IMPLIES *P* for any *P*). Therefore proving NOT *P* means providing that if it were true you would have a contradiction.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that property of contradictions you mention is known as [the principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), sometimes referred to as "ex falso quodlibet". Also, as an aside, `Void` is isomorphic to `forall a. a` (not really making a particular point, just thought that could be generally useful to mention).